# SOLR 6.6 crashes when using !join with facets

Tags: java, solr, nosql

I'm currently using SOLR 6.6 and encountering an issue. Whenever I use the !join operation in conjunction with facets, my SOLR server crashes.

Here is a query:

```
{!join from=some_core_id to=this_core_id fromIndex=some_core}*:*
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem or have any insights into why this might be happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

After some time I have next error appears on some_core:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":1},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException"],
    "msg":"Error opening new searcher",
    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:2069)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:2189)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1926)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1826)\n\tat org.apache.solr.request.SolrQueryRequestBase.getSearcher(SolrQueryRequestBase.java:127)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:310)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:296)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:724)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:530)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\nCaused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: Already closed\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.CachingDirectoryFactory.get(CachingDirectoryFactory.java:336)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getNewIndexDir(SolrCore.java:353)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1951)\n\t... 39 more\n",
    "code":500}}
```

The solution only is to restart SOLR server.
The **same query without Facets** works fine.

Thank you in advance!

Put the join query to filter query. The result is the same.